# Insert and Search Fields vb.net\asp.net web form to mssql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've created a page that spits out data from a table. I've gotten the update and delete functionality, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to search and add values. I threw in a few text boxes to mess around with, but I don't know how to make them into controls. I'd like to be able to search the data, as well as enter new data. How do I make these text boxes into search controls for the grid? Also how do I use text boxes or drop down boxes to insert new values into the table?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Bank Statements" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BankStatements.aspx.vb" Inherits="Compliance.BankStatements" %>

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>


<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
        <h2>Enter View and Edit Bank Statments Here<br />
        </h2>
    </hgroup>



    <br />

    Franchise ID:       
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; Year:&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="56px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; Month:&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;   

&nbsp;<asp:GridView 
            ID="GridView1" 
            runat="server" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
            ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" 
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
            AllowPaging="True"
    >

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FranchiseID" HeaderText="FranchiseID" SortExpression="FranchiseID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="Month" SortExpression="Month" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DatePosted" HeaderText="DatePosted" SortExpression="DatePosted" />    

    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />    
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
<hgroup>
</hgroup>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ComplianceConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand=
                    "SELECT FranchiseID, Year, Month, Amount, DatePosted, id FROM BankStmts  ORDER BY DatePosted DESC"
    DeleteCommand=
                    "DELETE 
                    FROM [BankStmts] 
                    WHERE id = @id"
    UpdateCommand=
                    "UPDATE [BankStmts] 
                    SET FranchiseID = @FranchiseID, Year = @Year, Month = @Month, Amount = @Amount, DatePosted = @DatePosted 
                    WHERE id = @id"
    InsertCommand=
                    "Insert INTO [BankStmts] FranchiseID, Year, Month, Amount, DatePosted 
                    VALUES @FranchiseID, @Year, @Month, @Amount, @DatePosted"
>

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FranchiseID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Year" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Month" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DatePosted" />
    </InsertParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FranchiseID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Year" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Month" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DatePosted" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>



</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do you really combine Html, ASP.NET, VB.NET and SQL in one large aspx file? Dear lord...Anyway, I'm failing to see your question.

Comment: Edited with questions. How do I make these text boxes into search controls for the grid? Also how do I use text boxes or drop down boxes to insert new values into the table?